# Extract random formula from nlme objects

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I'm trying to extract the random structure from models constructed using `lme`, but I can't seem to get anything other than the fixed formula. E.g.,

```
library(nlme)
fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age, Orthodont, random = ~ age | Subject)
deparse(terms(fm1))
# "distance ~ age"
```

This is possible for `lmer` using `findbars()`:

```
library(lmerTest)
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
findbars(formula(fm2))
# [[1]]
# Days | Subject
```

I want to be able to extract:

```
# ~ age | Subject
# (Days | Subject)
```

I could potentially get at this using `regexpr` but I would also like this to apply to more complex structures (multiple random slopes, nested random variables, etc.), and that might include additive or random slopes. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access these by

```
fm1$call$fixed
# distance ~ age
fm1$call$random
# ~age | Subject
```

Comment: D'oh! That was obvious. Thanks!